# prolog predicates - swap

Tags: prolog

I have an exam in Prolog today and am revising for it using old questions.

Would answer c be the incorrect answer?  Can anyone please explain this to me? It would be very helpful. Thank you,

Consider the following predicate:

```
swap([], []).
swap([X1, X2 | L], [X2, X1 | S]) :- swap(L, S).
```

Which of the following query and answer pairs is incorrect:

```
(a) ?- swap([a,b,c,d], S).
S = [b, a, d, c].

(b) ?- swap([a,b,d], H).
false.

(c) ?- swap([a,a,b,b], S).
S = [b, b, a, a].

(d) ?- swap([], S).
S = [].
```

Comment: C would be incorrect. Look carefully at the predicate and pretend you're the prolog interpreter. Then match your input with the roght clause and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(c) is indeed the incorrect answer. Item (c) has the following query:

```
swap([a,a,b,b], S).
```

If you run this query manually, it clearly doesn't match the clause `swap([], []).` It then does match the second clause: `swap([X1,X2|L], [X2,X1|S]) :-...`.

```
swap([a,  a,   b, b], S).
swap([X1, X2 | L],   [X2, X1 | S]) :- swap(L, S).
==> X1 = a, X2 = a, L = [b, b]
==> swap([a, a| [b,b]], [a, a | S]) :- swap([b, b], S).
```

Prolog can instantiate the first argument `[X1,X2|L]` with the given list, `[a,a,b,b]`. That, then, means `X1 = a`, `X2 = a`, and the rest of the list, `L = [b,b]`. Already from this information, you know that the list `[X2,X1|S]` is `[a,a|S]` but the answer shown by (c) is `[b,b,a,a]`. You don't even need to find out what `S` because since you know alrady that `[a,a|S]` isn't going to match `[b,b,a,a]`.